# Uploading video from form

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to allow users to upload videos to my website however I can't see where I have gone wrong. I am just trying to get them to upload to a folder first before also adding the file name to my database.

This is my form:

```
    <form action='videoUpload.php' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">



 <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $row['videoID'];?>'>



<p><label>Title</label><br />

<input type='text' name='videoTitle' required value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['videoTitle'];}?>'></p>



<p><label>Image</label><br />

<input type="file" name='video' id="video" required value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['video'];}?>'></p>



<p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></p>
```

and this is my php page:

```
<?php

require_once('../../../includes/config.php');

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {


            //collect form data

        extract($_POST);


$allowedExts = array("ogg", "mp4", "wma");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['video']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ((($_FILES["video"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
|| ($_FILES["video"]["type"] == "video/ogg")
|| ($_FILES["video"]["type"] == "video/wma")

&& ($_FILES["video"]["size"] < 50000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

  {
  if ($_FILES["video"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["video"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["video"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["video"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["video"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("../videos/" . $_FILES["video"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["video"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["video"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "../videos/" . $_FILES["video"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }

}
?>
```

Maybe it's something really simple that I'm but can't see where I've gone wrong

Comment: there are many errors in your php code!

Comment: Oh really? I was following it my from an example where people had been praising it

Comment: Would you be able to give me an indication of where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a `)` missing on if

```
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {


    //collect form data

    extract($_POST);


    $allowedExts = array("ogg", "mp4", "wma");
    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['video']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if ((($_FILES["video"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
        || ($_FILES["video"]["type"] == "video/ogg")
        || ($_FILES["video"]["type"] == "video/wma")

        && ($_FILES["video"]["size"] < 50000000)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))){ //comma missing


        if ($_FILES["video"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["video"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["video"]["name"] . "<br />";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["video"]["type"] . "<br />";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["video"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

            if (file_exists("../videos/" . $_FILES["video"]["name"]))
            {
                echo $_FILES["video"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
            else
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"],
                    "upload/" . $_FILES["video"]["name"]);
                echo "Stored in: " . "../videos/" . $_FILES["video"]["name"];
            }
        }

    }else{
        echo "Invalid file";
    }

}
```

Comment: damn, I'm an idiot, thank you for your help! got it working now

Comment: Don't worry it happens.